# Provide a recursive solution of this supply chain problem

Tags: java, database, algorithm, recursion, data-structures

Assume I've two tables Agreement and orders with the following structure.

Agreement Table

```
Product_ID  Seller  next_Supplier  SellingPrice
   1001        M       s1            90                                 
   1001       s1       s2            100
   1001       s1       s3            105
   1001       s1       s4            125
   1001       s2       s21           110
   1001       s3       s31           120
   1001       s4       s41           150
```

Think of it as a supply chain problem where there are various suppliers at each level and the supplier will take a from Manufacturer M and  will make an agreement to give a product to the next level supplier. The agreement table contains the agreement between various suppliers such s1 has made an agreement to give a product to s2 at $100.s2 ( the next level supplier for s1 ) has made an agreement to give the product to s21 at $110.s1 has also made an agreement to give the product to s3 and s4 at certain price.

Orders Table

```
Product_ID   Seller  Buyer  SellingPrice      
   1001        s21     c      125
   1001        s31     c      150
   1001        s41     c      200
```

Now finally s21 supplier has found out a customer c and sold to him the product at $125.Now as the product has been sold you need to write a java code on how the money will be distributed to the suppliers in the hierarchy. For Ex -  s21 will give $110 to s2 and s2 will $100 to s1 and s1 finally will give $90 to Manufacturer M.

I had written code for this but this is a iterative solution Below is the code.

```
List<Agreement> agreementList; // [select* from Agreement]
List<Order> ordersList; // [select* from Orders]

for(Order o : ordersList){
  String seller = o.Seller;

  for(Agreement a : agreementList) {
    if(a.next_Supplier == seller) {
      System.out.println(a.next_Supplier + " will give " + a.sellingprice + " to " + a.seller);
      seller = a.Seller;
    }
  }
}
```

I want to solve it recursively.But don't know how to achieve that.Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite to something like this:

```
List<Agreement> agreementList; // [select* from Agreement]
List<Order> ordersList; // [select* from Orders]

Map<String, Agreement> agreementsBySupplier = 
  agreementList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(a -> a.next_Supplier, Function.identity()));

for(Order o : ordersList){
  String seller = agreementsBySupplier.get(seller);

  System.out.println(a.next_Supplier + " will give " + a.sellingprice + " to " + a.seller);
}
```

This still traverses all the agreements once obviously (and also loads all of them in memory).

If you really want to make this efficient, you'd use a different `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders o LEFT JOIN Agreement a ON o.seller = a.next_Supplier;
```

Comment: We need such kind of output - s21 will give $110 to s2 and s2 will $100 to s1 and s1 finally will give $90 to Manufacturer M.This sql query will give only for s21.